# Disable site when ie access in quirks mode

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

i'm trying to disable my website when a user access the site in ie and use the quirks mode, someone know a script in php or javascript that disable or verify this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you missing a doctype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [document.compatMode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.compatMode) and see if it matches `"CSS1Compat"`.

```
var isQuirky = (document.compatMode !== 'CSS1Compat');
if (isQuirky === true) {
  alert('Your browser is rendering this page in quirks mode, and it may not display properly.');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check it using document.compatMode property

if document.compatMode is CSS1Compat then the mode is standard otherwise it is Quirk

```
document.compatMode==='CSS1Compat'?'Standards':'Quirks') + ' mode.'
```